# Cut scenes and dialogue lines always end prematurely

Tags: starcraft-2

All my cut scenes and conversations in the single player HotS end about half a second too soon. For example, during dialogues, person B starts talking while person A is still speaking out his last word from the previous sentence. Cut scenes also end prematurely, as I can tell from the background music, and sometimes the last word of the speech, being cut.

This is really annoying. Is there anyone else experiencing the same problem? How can I fix it?

Comment: I would update all drivers on the system.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This normally happens when the PCI bus is overclocked and your sound device is a Realtek onboard chip.  I think the slightly faster PCI clock is causing the on-board sound timer to run fast, so if you have a 3% overclock, and are playing a 30 second clip, it will cut off one second sooner.

The sad part is that many motherboards come with an automatic small overclock to make them faster than their competitors, so even if you don't think you are overclocking your motherboard, you may be.

If you know how to, go into your BIOS and try removing any FSB or PCI overclocking and see if that fixes the issue.  If you don't know what those acronyms are however, don't try it!

Comment: That's pretty specific, do you have a reference?

Comment: Here is a discussion of it in ME2 http://social.bioware.com/forum/1/topic/106/index/1501945/3  Here is a guy who had the same issue with SC2 and ME2 http://benmurden.com/?p=82   I know I discussed it in some Dragon Age forums, but can't find them at the moment.

Comment: You are absolutely correct. I tried to overclock more, the problem got worse; when I underclock, the interval between dialogues got longer! You are very insightful!